# C function fork()

Tags: c, fork

i wanted to find someone that can explain this to me. I have this program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  printf("P ");
  if(fork()==0)
     printf("C ");
  return 0;
}
```

The result of this program is: P P C

What's the reason for that second "P" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IO buffering is the reason. `printf` is not printing the text right away, but waiting for newline, `fflush` or the end of the program to actually print it. But the buffer for the "future-to-print" text is in the memory that is getting duplicated by `fork`, so both processes receive it. And in the end both are printing it.

Comment: So, when i do fork, in the buffer stays "P ", and so when i prinf("C ") he imprimes them both?

Comment: Yes. Try to add `\n` after `P`, the behavior should change.